# I need a batch or a command line to restart the ''process<name>'' 2 minutes after the process is over

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch or a command line to restart the ''process'' 2 minutes after the process is over.I have a script maybe u can help me add the line there, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will start the program and wait for it to terminate. Once the program is terminated, the script will wait two minutes before starting the program again.

```
start "" /wait "process"
timeout /t 120
start "" "process"
```

Comment: can u add this lines on this script please ? https://pastebin.com/ip3sKkAA